# AngularJS sharing data between factory & controller across modules

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I have an angularjs app that has several modules. The main modules looks something like:

```
var app = angular.module('mainMod', ['apiService']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function (Socket) {
    $scope.objects = {};
    // do something with $scope.objects, etc.
});
```

And then I have;

```
var apiService = angular.module('apiService', ['ngResource']); // etc
```

and;

```
apiService.factory('Socket', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    // create a websocket and listen for stuff
    // if something happens, update 'objects' in $rootScope
}]);
```

The thing is, I see that the service `Socket` has been injected in `MainCtrl`, but inside the `Socket` service, I can not access `$rootScope.objects`. I do understand that factories have no scopes of their own, but since its injected into `MainCtrl`, shouldn't the rootscope refer to the scope of the `MainCtrl`?

There is a workaround using events, but I'm not too keen on that. I have tried it with success but I'd prefer a solution where this just works.

Comment: Where is the code that assigns the objects to $rootScope?

Comment: My assumption is that `$scope` from `MainCtrl` can be referred to (somehow) from the `Socket` factory. So, quite obviously, the use of `$rootScope` would be wrong. So to refine the question, I'd like a replacement for `$rootScope` in `Socket` so that I refer to the scope `Socket` was injected into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to inject the `$scope` into your controller itself:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Socket) {
    $scope.objects = {};
   // do something with $scope.objects, etc.
});
```

But this still won´t help you to access the "objects" of this controller via the rootScope, since $scope inherhits $rootScope, but not the other way around - so whatever you define on the `$scope` wont be propagated to the `$rootScope`.

What you CAN do however is to link the `$scope.objects` with a varibale inside your factory itself, so something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('mainMod', ['apiService']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function (Socket) {
   $scope.objects = Socket.objects = {};
    // do something with $scope.objects, etc.
});
```

And in your Socket-Factory:

```
apiService.factory('Socket', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
       objects : {}
   }
}]);
```

Just be careful then to not overwrite the `$scope.objects` directly, since it will break the reference again.