# myfunction() function call from one controller to another in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

i have used Angularjs  and i wanna call getcustomer function from one controller to another controller i have so many doing gooogling but i don't have an idea that how to call that
i have write below code which i used

```
      var app = angular.module('Napp', []);
            app.controller('GetAlphabetical', function ($scope, $http) {

      function getCutomers() {
                $scope.loading = true;
                $http.get('@Url.Content("~/Home/GetPesrons")').then(function (response) {
                    //var _data = angular.fromJson(response);
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    $scope.Customer = response.data; // please check the request response if list id in data object 
                }, function (error) {
                    throw error;
                })
            }
    });



and second controller :

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
getCutomers()
});
```

Comment: Generally its called a bad practice. You should start thinking to use either `service` or `factory`. You will found many articles of doing that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511986/angularjs-sharing-data-between-factory-controller-across-modules will help you.

Comment: ya i know may possible you are right but i'm new in angularjs

Comment: use "factory or service" instead of module to write global methods

Comment: check for $broadcast, $emit and $on

http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/XqDxG/

Answer (score 1):

Mate, you will have to follow the following steps to resolve your problem. Firstly you have you create a factory

```
   angular
    .module('Napp')
    .factory('CustomerFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
      var _factory = {};

      _factory.getCustomers = function () {
        return $http.get('@Url.Content("~/Home/GetPesrons")');
      };

      return _factory;
    }]);
```

Then you can share data and functions between multiple controllers or services

**GetAlphabetical Controller :**

```
   angular
    .module('Napp')
    .controller('GetAlphabetical', ['$scope', 'CustomerFactory', function ($scope, CustomerFactory) {

      loadCustomers();

      function loadCustomers() {
        CustomerFactory.getCustomers().then(function (successResponse) {
          $scope.Customer = successResponse.data; // please check the request response if list id in data object 
        }, function (errorResponse) {
          throw error;
        })
      }

    }]);
```

**MainCtrl Controller :**

```
  angular
    .module('Napp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'CustomerFactory', function ($scope, CustomerFactory) {

      loadCustomers();

      function loadCustomers() {
        CustomerFactory.getCustomers().then(function (successResponse) {
          $scope.Customer = successResponse.data; // please check the request response if list id in data object 
        }, function (errorResponse) {
          throw error;
        })
      }

    }]);
```

Comment: You may wish to load data in one controller and use the same data in different controller. if this is your challenge then you can save your data in factory and access in different controllers.

Comment: Yes you are saying absolutely right i will try you idea

Comment: Mohan please see my problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152583/call-function-from-one-controller-to-another-controller-using-factory-in-angular?noredirect=1#comment52193975_32152583

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to somehow communicate between two controllers. This can be easily be achieved using [$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) & [$on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on).

Incase there is a parent child relation between your controllers, use the following.

```
function firstCtrl($scope){
    $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', [1,2,3]);
}

function secondCtrl($scope){
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, mass) {console.log(mass)});
}
```

If there is no parent child relationship between your controller, then inject [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) and broadcast using that.

related question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14502755/1182982

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by defining it as a `service` and injecting it as a dependency.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('helloWorldFromService', function() {
    this.sayHello = function() {
        return "Hello, World!"
    };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, helloWorldFromService) {

app.controller('GetAlphabetical', function ($scope, $http, helloWorldFromService) {
```

### **<kbd>[Angular Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)</kbd>**