# Call function from one controller to another controller using Factory in Angularjs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-services

I wanna call function from one contoller to another using used of  factory mathod in angularjs below are the code which i used

```
var Inciapp = angular.module('IncidentApp', []);

Inciapp.controller('GetAlphabetical', function ($scope, CustomerFactory) {
    $scope.Customer = null;
    CustomerFactory.getCustomers().then(function (successResponse) {
        $scope.Customer = successResponse.data; // please check the request response if list id in data object 
    }, function (errorResponse) {
        throw error;
    })
});

Inciapp.factory('CustomerFactory',function ($http) {
    var _factory = {};
    _factory.getCustomers = function () {
        return $http.get('@Url.Content("~/Home/GetIncidentlist")');
    };
    return _factory;
});
```

HTML :

```
 <div data-ng-app="IncidentApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="GetAlphabetical">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>IncidentID</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr ng-repeat="h in Customer">
                    <td>{{ h.Name }}</td>

                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
<div data-ng-controller="GetAlphabeticalSecond">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>IncidentID</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr ng-repeat="h in Customer">
                    <td>{{ h.Name }}</td>

                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

C# :

```
 List<incident> lst = new List<incident>();
        lst.Add(new incident { ID = "123", contact = "98765", IDcontact = "456", IDnumber = "7866", Name = "Nayeem", NameID = "3333", number = "987654321", Phone = "1234567890" });
        lst.Add(new incident { ID = "123", contact = "98765", IDcontact = "456", IDnumber = "7866", Name = "Nayeem", NameID = "3333", number = "987654321", Phone = "1234567890" });
        lst.Add(new incident { ID = "123", contact = "98765", IDcontact = "456", IDnumber = "7866", Name = "Nayeem", NameID = "3333", number = "987654321", Phone = "1234567890" });
        lst.Add(new incident { ID = "123", contact = "98765", IDcontact = "456", IDnumber = "7866", Name = "Nayeem", NameID = "3333", number = "987654321", Phone = "1234567890" });
        lst.Add(new incident { ID = "123", contact = "98765", IDcontact = "456", IDnumber = "7866", Name = "Nayeem", NameID = "3333", number = "987654321", Phone = "1234567890" });
        lst.Add(new incident { ID = "123", contact = "98765", IDcontact = "456", IDnumber = "7866", Name = "Nayeem", NameID = "3333", number = "987654321", Phone = "1234567890" });
        lst.Add(new incident { ID = "123", contact = "98765", IDcontact = "456", IDnumber = "7866", Name = "Nayeem", NameID = "3333", number = "987654321", Phone = "1234567890" });
        lst.Add(new incident { ID = "123", contact = "98765", IDcontact = "456", IDnumber = "7866", Name = "Nayeem", NameID = "3333", number = "987654321", Phone = "1234567890" });
        lst.Add(new incident { ID = "123", contact = "98765", IDcontact = "456", IDnumber = "7866", Name = "Nayeem", NameID = "3333", number = "987654321", Phone = "1234567890" });
        return Json(lst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: nothing don't have any error

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: don't have any error

Comment: you closed your `data-ng-app` div tag before your `data-ng-controller="GetAlphabeticalSecond"` div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated View File**

```
   <div data-ng-app="IncidentApp">
      <!-- angular IncidentApp scope starts from here -->

      <div data-ng-controller="GetAlphabetical">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>IncidentID</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr ng-repeat="h in Customer">
              <td>{{ h.Name }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>

    <div data-ng-controller="GetAlphabeticalSecond">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>IncidentID</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
          <tr ng-repeat="h in Customer">
            <td>{{ h.Name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>

   <!-- angular IncidentApp scope ends from here --> 
  </div>
```

> Angular stuff only works if they comes in application scope. In your case GetAlphabetical is in application scope but second controller were out of scope. i have updated the HTML view to fix your issue.

Comment: mohan please solve my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263313/how-to-open-popover-for-update-my-record-in-angularjs problem

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is out of the scope of the app.

The div that encloses the ng-controller should be inside the div that encloses the ng-app.