# How to open popover for update my record in ANgularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive

Friends,

I waant to update my record using popover and i have to used angularjs directive.my popover is open but data not populated in textbox and update button click not working 
below my cod which i used

SCRIPT :

```
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.days = [{ 'ID': 1, 'name': 'Sunday' },
        { 'ID': 2, 'name': 'Monday' },
        { 'ID': 3, 'name': 'Tuesday' },
        { 'ID': 4, 'name': 'Wednesday' },
        { 'ID': 5, 'name': 'Thursday' },
        { 'ID': 6, 'name': 'Friday' },
        { 'ID': 7, 'name': 'Saturday' }];

    $scope.editSave = function () {
        alert('Update!');
    }

    $scope.ProphenDelete = function () {
        alert('Delete!');
    }

});

mymodal.directive('bsPopover', function () {

    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var popOverContent = "<modal title='Add/Update/Delete'>"
                                + '<form role="form">'
                                + '<div class="form-group">'
                                + '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt" ng-bind="modedit.editProfaneWord" ng-model="editProfaneWord"/>'
                                + '<input type="hidden" name="someData"  ng-model="ID" /> '
                                + '</div>'
                                + '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editSave()">Save</button>&nbsp;'
                                 + '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ProphenDelete()">Delete</button>'
                                + '</form></modal>';
        element.find("a[rel=popover]").popover({
            placement: 'bottom',
            html: 'true',
            content: popOverContent,
            title: attrs.popoverPlacement
        });
    };


});
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="mymodal">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="cust in days" bs-popover>
            <td>
                <a rel="popover" ng-bind="cust.name"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I use Ionic Popover like this $scope.popover = $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('someHTML', {
        scope: $scope // here i pass the scope so scope works in popover
    }).then(function (popover) {
        $scope.popover = popover;
    }); you should be able to pass scope to the popover

Comment: could you please write the code how can i used

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/ivankovachev/U4GLT/light/

Comment: no, friend i wanna like this http://plnkr.co/edit/W9BWMc3x5khuaMEL7lp1?p=preview
but i wanna Nayeem Mansoori in popover title bar

Comment: well then look at the html file in the button there is  a confirm-title there you need to change it to Nayeem Mansoori

Comment: My title popover is dynamically changed, becouse my list is increase and i will click it, item so title bar is which is i click

Comment: @NayeemMansoori you should use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover this directive. In this directive you can create your custom template and create popover controller

Comment: well then you do confirm-title="{{dynamicValue}}" and in your directive or controller you say $scope / scope dynamicValue is your listthingy

Comment: @Mohan you are right but i dont know how its use...my fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/Nayeem_Mansoori/ob9r4d37/

Comment: thanks mohan.....i appreciate

Comment: @NayeemMansoori Please have a look at plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/k1QOIMpPLm1nYLZd8Txe?p=preview

Comment: mohan greastsssss but i want to click sunday so popuptitle and textbox value is sunday

Comment: And at a time only one popover open

Comment: any one answsers my questions